# What word describes someone that hides in public?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

For example a public figure, celebrity, authority, teacher that secretly conducts unlawful or unsavoury behaviour. Is there a specific word for this?

Comment: [Surreptitious](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/surreptitious#synonym-discussion). See discussion under synonyms. Please add a sentence or two with a blank to help define the word type and register you are after.

Comment: Every question should describe the asker's prior efforts to find an answer, and explain why the results were not adequate to answer the question. Some research is required on every question. This is called our research requirement. Research can take many forms: checking references such as an online English dictionary, thesaurus, or grammar, searching this site for similar questions, searching the web, or putting substantial thought into the question on your own. Please [edit] your question and detail your research results.

Answer (score 1):

Not to riff too much on *surreptitious* (+1), but I'd say better options are *clandestine* and *furtive*.

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/clandestine
https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/furtive